# Rename levels using wildcard matching in r

Tags: r

Is it possible to replace the levels using wildcard matching in R?

I have a column named years of experience values as `"0 YEAR, 9 MONTHS"`,   `"1 YEAR, 0 MONTHS"`,   `"1 YEAR, 1 MONTHS"`,   `"1 YEAR, 10 MONTHS"`, `"1 YEAR, 9 MONTHS"`,   `"10 YEAR, 0 MONTHS"`,  `"10 YEAR, 1 MONTHS"`,  `"10 YEAR, 10 MONTHS"`, like-wise nearly 600 levels; I wish to bucket all `"0 YEAR...` as `"<1"`, `1 YEAR` as `"1"`, more than `5 YEAR` as `">5"`, giving 5 levels in total.

```
grep("9 YEAR", data$Service, ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)
```

Tried `mutate` and I can't exactly narrow down for each level, I expect only to get 5 or 6 levels finally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's generate some random sample data

```
set.seed(2018)
x <- factor(paste(sample(0:10, 10, replace = T), "YEAR,", sample(0:11, 10, replace = T), "MONTHS"))
df <- data.frame(years_of_experience = x)
#   years_of_experience
#1     3 YEAR, 4 MONTHS
#2     5 YEAR, 7 MONTHS
#3    0 YEAR, 11 MONTHS
#4     2 YEAR, 8 MONTHS
#5     5 YEAR, 9 MONTHS
#6     3 YEAR, 7 MONTHS
#7     6 YEAR, 3 MONTHS
#8     1 YEAR, 6 MONTHS
#9    10 YEAR, 8 MONTHS
#10    6 YEAR, 9 MONTHS
```

Then we can use `case_when` to bin `years_of_experience` based on the years

```
df.new <- df %>%
    mutate(
        yr = as.numeric(gsub(" YEAR.*$", "", x)),
        bucket = case_when(
            yr < 1 ~ "<1",
            yr >= 5 ~ ">=5",
            TRUE ~ as.character(yr)))
df.new
#   years_of_experience yr bucket
#1     3 YEAR, 4 MONTHS  3      3
#2     5 YEAR, 7 MONTHS  5    >=5
#3    0 YEAR, 11 MONTHS  0     <1
#4     2 YEAR, 8 MONTHS  2      2
#5     5 YEAR, 9 MONTHS  5    >=5
#6     3 YEAR, 7 MONTHS  3      3
#7     6 YEAR, 3 MONTHS  6    >=5
#8     1 YEAR, 6 MONTHS  1      1
#9    10 YEAR, 8 MONTHS 10    >=5
#10    6 YEAR, 9 MONTHS  6    >=5
```

We can convert `df.new$bucket` to a `factor` which has 5 levels

```
df.new %>% mutate(bucket = as.factor(bucket)) %>% pull(bucket)
# [1] 3   >=5 <1  2   >=5 3   >=5 1   >=5 >=5
#Levels: <1 >=5 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks, got an issue that yr return only NA for me

Comment: @prem Difficult to debug without sample data; you should edit your post and include minimal & representative sample data using `dput`. This definitely works on the sample data that I generate.

Comment: yes, your code is working, yr returns corresponding values, in my data x is data$yr_service, df is data, as obvious yr is a local, do i have to take out my variable  and store separately as data.frame?

Comment: yes working, actually i replaced missing values as "d_missing" so for that it is generating NA, now i changed missing as 0 YEAR, 0 MONTHS.
```{r}
x <- data$yr_Service
dfyr <- data.frame(x)

x <- dfyr %>%
  mutate(yr = as.numeric(gsub(" YEAR.*$", "", x)),
    bucket = case_when(yr < 1 ~ "<1",
                       yr >= 5 ~ ">=5",
                       TRUE ~ as.character(yr)))
x$bucket
```
May i know how to put back in the data

Comment: I changes as factor and assigned back, Thanks, i the code may know how it is generating only 6 levels

Comment: @prem I am not quite sure what you're asking. When I convert `bucket` to a `factor`, `bucket` has 5 levels (see my edit). How do you end up with 6 levels? Again, difficult to help without any sample data.

Comment: It is working, Thank you very much, In the sample data there is no 4 years, my data got that so getting 6 levels at the end

Comment: @prem If you don't have entries with `"YEAR 4 ..."` you should get one *less* `factor` level, i.e. 5 instead of 6; or am I missing something? To avoid this you could give explicit `factor` levels, e.g. `df.new %>% mutate(bucket = as.factor(bucket, levels = c("<1", "1", "2", "3", "4", ">=5"))`

Comment: The sample data i meant is yours, which don't have 4 year, mine has 4 YEAR, Thanks

Comment: For the same on cleaning the test data where we get only one record which may contains any one of that strings, may I know how to replace that for particular match?

Comment: For Only One incoming Predcition Record, I tried like
if(substring(df$Service, 1, 1) == "0"){
  df$Service <- "<1"
} else if(substring(df$Service, 1, 1) == "1"){
  df$Service <- "<2"
} and so on

Is there a better way